# Binary tree monad implementation

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, monads

I have difficulties to understand how to correctly implement the (>>=) for the monad of binary tree. I have the following binary tree :

```
data BinTree a = Leaf a | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) 
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

Here's the (>>=) operator for my monad :

```
Node x l r >>= f = Node (f x) (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
                 __________^
```

I keep getting this error :

```
Couldn't match type `b' with `BinTree b'
`b' is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for
    >>= :: BinTree a -> (a -> BinTree b) -> BinTree b
  at test.hs:153:5
 In the return type of a call of `f'
 In the first argument of `Node', namely `(f x)'
 In the expression: Node (f x) (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
```

So I don't understand how I can obtain a proper leaf of the correct type?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `Node` says that the first value in the constructor has
type `a`, but you are attempting to insert a `BinTree a` into the node value.
What you need to do is bind the result of `f x` and use that as the value for
the new node.

```
(Node x l r) >>= f = f x >>= \y -> Node y (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't thought of binding the result.

Comment: IMO, the parens on the LHS make it rather less readable. I'd prefer writing this `Node x l r >>= f` \n `= f x >>= ...`.

Comment: I implemented the Monad typeclass the same way. It compiles fine, however, when executing this one it always ends up in an infinite loop. 

From my point of view it is impossible to implement the Monad typeclass for this Tree-type. Or am I wrong?